# Can access to my site while it is available (on http://validator.w3.org)

Tags: validation, web

I want to check HTML validate (validator.w3.org) and create site map from xml-sitemaps.com

My wbsite: game.tocdo.vn

I received error on validator.w3.org:

> - I got the following unexpected response when trying to retrieve http://game.tocdo.vn/:
>
>   500 Can't connect to game.tocdo.vn:80 (connect: Connection timed out)

I received error on xml-sitemaps.com:

> There was an error while accessing the URL specified: http://game.tocdo.vn/
>   Please make sure to specify the correct website URL and resubmit your request.

In this time, my website still access normaly. What happen to my website?

Help me please. Thanks!

Comment: Your site doesn't appear to be online. I cannot access it.

Comment: It works on validator.w3.org just fine. I got 'Errors found while checking this document as XHTML 1.0 Transitional!'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's working? Have you tried accessing it from a device other than one on your current network?

It's possible that you have internal DNS rules which are making it look like the site is accessible from within your network, but it's not configured to work outside of it.

You can always copy and paste the html source of your page into the validator and that will give the desired results.

Comment: thank you so much, i dont know why my website   doesn't appear to be online outside of my country. In my country, my website is working.